# Export Customer ListID from QB

Tags: quickbooks

I am writing a program to import various client's QB customers into a database.

After the import, I need to synchronize information between the database and QB, so I use the Customer ListID.

This is no problem to get when I can connect to the clients computer and query their customers with QB SDK, however this is difficult to do in many cases.

I know the client can export a csv or iif file for Customers, but this does not include the ListID.

Is there anyway to get the ListID field with the Customer list from the QuickBooks interface without having to use QB SDK?

Rick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get the ListIDs without the use of some sort of SDK program.